# Cannot localize iPad app name in "Open in"

Tags: ios, ipad, localization

I have set CFBundleDisplayName and CFBundleName in InfoPlist.strings. The app name is correctly localized on the iPad main screen and under the app list in settings.

However, I cannot get it to be localized in "Open in" app list when I try launch my app by opening PDF files from other application. The app name is also not localized in the app list of File Sharing on iTunes on my Mac. They always display the ${PRODUCT_NAME} instead.

Other notes: I have set CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations and LSHasLocalizedDisplayName to true, and CFBundleDevelopmentRegion to English. CFBundleDisplayName and CFBundleName are set to ${PRODUCT_NAME} in Info.plist (default settings).

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a bug that needs filing, I am not aware of any workarounds. http://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: Damn, I think I may need to have a separate version for each localization, but this is the route I really don't want to take...